# I am trying to upload an file to a shared folder, the folder is shared by other user , need to add an file using api,

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

This is the pattern url pattern i tried

```
POST
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{shareduserdriveid}/items/{shareduserFolderitemId}, 

{
  "name": "Team Documents",
  "remoteItem": {

      "parentReference": { "driveId": "sharedusersdriveid" }
  }
}
```

Can someone please provide right url and body pattern for adding or uploading an file to a existing shared folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to POST to the children collection, so a url like the one below should work:

POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{shareduserdriveid}/items/{shareduserFolderitemId}/children

```
{
"name":"test.txt",
"file": {}
}
```